# svn checkout fails with a TLS warning alert

Tags: svn, ssl, centos, tls1.2

I have two CentOS linux on my VMware one of them is `CentOS 6.2 32bit` and the other is `CentOS 6.4 64bit` they are both connected to my network using bridge mode and have seperate ip but when i try to do a svn checkout on `CentOS 6.2 32bit` i get the folowing error:

> root:shell> svn co https://192.168.18.12/repos/src/myproject
>
> svn: OPTIONS of 'https://192.168.18.12/repos/src/myproject': SSL handshake failed: SSL error: A TLS warning alert has been received. (https://192.168.18.12)

but i have no problem with svn in `CentOS 6.4 64bit` and everything works great.

what exactly the error means? and how can i solve this?

PS : svn version on both Linuxes is 1.6.11 (r934486)
and i can say i have another user (exept root) in my `CentOS 6.4 64bit` (that works ok) but in my faulty `CentOS 6.2 32bit` linux i have just a root account and no other user (if this is relevant to the subject).

PS2 : i can successfully ping that ip and it's opens correctly in firefox browser using my username and password for the svn repos.

**UPDATE**

I'm posting my `ssl.config` file here as well:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

And when i get `apachectl configtest` that answers with:

> httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
>   Syntax OK

Answer (score 0):

A possible error could be a mismatch between the address used on the svn command line and the ServerName in the ssl.conf of apache. 
Try to update the ServerName in the ssl.conf file.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, i'm not trying to connect with a name i'm using server ip directly and i can't find anything wrong in my ssl.config file

Comment: ok, so your ssl conf is correct...you should do more debug, you can do  a tcpdump port 443 -s0 -w error.cap so you can see more details on your error.

Comment: By the way, you are receiving a TLS warning so you should get more details on the warning and, then, you can refear to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security to verify the typology of error. At the bottom of the page there is a table with all the possible alert and their meanings.

Comment: ok i added my ssl.config and i'm going to look into that table

Comment: i only get `A TLS warning alert has been received.` and no information about the actual warning so i can't use that table here

Comment: Try to add the server name on your ssl.config. To do so, just add the line ServerName 192.x.x.x right under <VirtualHost _default_:443>. Just to be sure that is not a server name mapping problem.

Comment: i add that and no result but when i get `apachectl configtest` that answers with `httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
Syntax OK`

Comment: Ok, then I may assume that you haven't a qualified name in your httpd.conf file. Event if you use a virtual host you still need a qualified name in your httpd conf. Open the file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and add the line ServerName [your-ip-address]. Then restart the apache server.

Comment: i dont have any apache2 folder

Comment: Check here: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf